# Firma xades epes en XML

Tags: java, xml, firma-digital, xades4j

Estoy intentando firmar un documento xml en JAVA para la facturación electrónica en Colombia, y encontré unas librerías como xades4j, pero a la hora de incluir el jar de ésta librería en mi proyecto y usar uno de sus ejemplos, me sale que inclusive algunas funciones ya no sirven.

Alguno de ustedes sabe como firmar con ésta librería, o alguna librería que me sirva para éste mismo propósito?

Se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: saludos lo lograste ?

Comment: puedes colocar un Issue en el repositorio con tu problema --> https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j